# How many words in a string are capitalized?

Tags: google-sheets, text

I have some text in a cell (let's say `A1`) in Google Sheets and wish to count how many words have initial capital letters. I've tried a couple of things, but neither works:

```
=countif(split(A1," "),regexmatch(split(A1," "),"^\W*[A-Z]"))
```

```
=sum(arrayformula(regexmatch(text(split(A1," "),0),"^\W*[A-Z]")))
```

What should I be doing, please?

---

A couple of notes:

- I want to do this for multiple cells, i.e. to know how many words in `A1` are capitalized, how many in `A2` are, etc. I doubt that that will affect the answer, but am mentioning it just in case.
- The regular expression I used above is not a good way to check for capitalization in general, and don't use it. (See e.g. the "brokenness" section of [Tom Christiansen's "Go Thou and Do Likewise" post on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/552647). It's about Perl, but much of it generalizes.) It happens to work for my data, because my data uses a specific set of characters that it happens to work for. You have been warned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I wound up doing (though I would still love to see an in-place solution, by which I mean one that doesn't require the use of additional cells):

I created two additional tabs (worksheets). In the first I put `=split(A!A1," ")`, which yielded a row of words, one per cell. I called that worksheet "`split`". In the second I put `=if(not(regexmatch(text(split!A1,0),"^\W*[A-Za-z]")),,regexmatch(text(split!A1,0),"^\W*[A-Z]"))` and copied it across the row to get the truth value in each cell of whether the word has an initial capital letter. Then I added column `A` to the left containing `=if(counta(B1:Z1)=0,,countif(B1:Z1,true))`.